# Add custom field in Nebular Register Component

Tags: angular, nebular

I have setup authentication for nebular using all of their components and used `NbPasswordAuthStrategy` as authentication strategy.

The register component currently has following inputs,

1. Full Name
2. Email
3. Password
4. Repeat Password

***But my API requires me to have First Name and Last Name instead of Full Name.*** How do I go about configuring the framework so that it fits my custom needs?

I have researched on how to do this, but came up with no results. Neither the `NbPasswordAuthStrategy` setup has any way to customise the form nor there is an example provided for customising the form.

My Authentication config looks like this

```
{
  strategies: [
    NbPasswordAuthStrategy.setup({
      name: 'email',
      token: {
        class: NbAuthJWTToken,
        key: 'token'
      },
      baseEndpoint: 'api',
      login: {
        endpoint: '/auth/login',
        redirect: {
          success: '/pages/dashboard',
          failure: null,
        },
      },
      register: {endpoint: '/auth/register'},
    }),
  ],
  forms: {
    logout: {
      strategy: 'email'
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize auth components via auth module configuration instead you need to extend and customize Nebular auth components. Here is a [guide](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/custom-auth-components#custom-auth-components).

Comment: I have done it using the guide. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you done this? How to add firstName and lastName to component? How do you customize the user class. Pls reply

Answer (score 0):

You can just change payload like this

```
  this.nbAuthService.authenticate('register', {
    fullName: 'fullName',
    password: 'password',
    email: 'email',
    repeatedPassword: 'repeatedPassword',
  }).subscribe(data => {
    this.router.navigate([data.getRedirect()]);
  });
```